# How do I move a Project from TFS to Git in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I have an existing project in Visual Studio Online that is currently using TFS for source control, how can it be changed to git?

I see numerous articles on renaming but not changing the Source Control.

Answer (score 3):

With https://gittf.codeplex.com/, you can take your existing Team Project using TFVC, convert it into a Git repository, and then use the regular Git tools to push the repository into your new Git Team Project. It's pretty straightforward.

Given how TFVC handles branches versus how Git handles branches, you may need to massage the structure of your source code a little bit after the migration.